# Implement c# asp.net application with WCF service (wshttpBinding) using JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

I need to implement c# asp.net application with WCF service (wshttpBinding) using JSON.

I have one aspx page that need to display one table. Table data coming from WCF service with wshttpBinding. I can do this by using code behind. But I need to implement this by only client side (renduring) using JSON.

```
groupUsers.InnerHtml = showUsers(); 

showuser() {
   strBuilder.Append("<table width='40%' align='center' runat='server'>"); 
   List<string> GroupUsers = client.GetADGroupUsers(ddlGroupNames.SelectedValue); 
   int i = 1; 
   strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' ><td> ID </td><td> Name </td></tr>"); 
   foreach (string user in GroupUsers) { 
      int ID = i++; 
      string Name = user; 
      strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left'><td>" + ID + "</td><td>" + Name + "</td></tr>"); 
   } 
   strBuilder.Append("</table>"); 
   return strBuilder
}
```

Comment: can you show your code ? what have you tried

Comment: at submit button groupUsers.InnerHtml = showUsers();
and in showuser()
      strBuilder.Append("<table width='40%' align='center' runat='server'>");
      List<string> GroupUsers = client.GetADGroupUsers(ddlGroupNames.SelectedValue);
      int i = 1;
strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' ><td> ID </td><td> Name </td></tr>");
        foreach (string user in GroupUsers)
        {
          int ID = i++;
          string Name = user;
          strBuilder.Append("<tr align='left'><td>" + ID + "</td><td>" + Name + "</td></tr>");
        }
strBuilder.Append("</table>");
      return strBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Might be this is what you are looking for

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide